# Conversion to_datetime error, unrecognized value type

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, jupyter

I have a flights.csv Database of flights taking off and landing on a particular airport and times associated with each flight step, i.e. Departure, Wheels off the ground, Wheels on the ground, Arrival, Actual Arrival and Departure, etc.

Now I want to convert the times given in the database in the form of floats in 24hr format
For eg: 13:45 is 1345.0
00:02 is 0002.0

Two of these columns (Scheduled_departure and Scheduled arrival) are in integers, so it's very easy for me to convert them into time by:

`flights['SCHEDULED_DEPARTURE'] = flights['SCHEDULED_DEPARTURE'].apply(lambda x: '{0:0>4}'.format(x))`

(To add zeroes before the time number)

`flights['SCHEDULED_DEPARTURE'] = pd.to_datetime(flights['SCHEDULED_DEPARTURE'],format= '%H%M').dt.time`

(For actual conversion`

But since the other columns are in floats, I cannot directly use astype() since it creates an error for the decimal.

So I tried to bypass my way by:

`pd.to_numeric(flights.DEPARTURE_TIME, downcast = 'integer')`

(To remove the decimals)

`flights.DEPARTURE_TIME = flights.DEPARTURE_TIME.astype(dtype='int32')`

(For redundancy for the next step)

`flights['DEPARTURE_TIME'] = flights['DEPARTURE_TIME'].apply(lambda x: '{0:0>4}'.format(x))`

(To add zeroes before the number)

`flights['DEPARTURE_TIME'] = pd.to_datetime(flights['DEPARTURE_TIME'],format= '%H%M').dt.time`

(For actual time conversion)

But after this step, it outputs an error:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
    ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py in _convert_listlike_datetimes(arg, box, format, name, tz, unit, errors, infer_datetime_format, dayfirst, yearfirst, exact)
        290             try:
    --> 291                 values, tz = conversion.datetime_to_datetime64(arg)
        292                 return DatetimeIndex._simple_new(values, name=name, tz=tz)

    pandas/_libs/tslibs/conversion.pyx in 
    pandas._libs.tslibs.conversion.datetime_to_datetime64()

    TypeError: Unrecognized value type: <class 'str'>

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-23-a3defb9ecd52> in <module>
    ----> 1 flights['DEPARTURE_TIME'] = 
    pd.to_datetime(flights['DEPARTURE_TIME'],format= '%H%M').dt.time

    ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py in 
    to_datetime(arg, errors, dayfirst, yearfirst, utc, box, format, exact, 
    unit, infer_datetime_format, origin, cache)
     590         else:
     591             from pandas import Series
 --> 592             values = convert_listlike(arg._values, True, format)
     593             result = Series(values, index=arg.index, name=arg.name)
     594     elif isinstance(arg, (ABCDataFrame, compat.MutableMapping)):

    ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py in 
    _convert_listlike_datetimes(arg, box, format, name, tz, unit, errors, 
    infer_datetime_format, dayfirst, yearfirst, exact)
         292                 return DatetimeIndex._simple_new(values, name=name, tz=tz)
         293             except (ValueError, TypeError):
     --> 294                 raise e
         295 
         296     if result is None:

    ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py in 
    _convert_listlike_datetimes(arg, box, format, name, tz, unit, errors, 
    infer_datetime_format, dayfirst, yearfirst, exact)
        259                 try:
        260                     result, timezones = array_strptime(
    --> 261                         arg, format, exact=exact, errors=errors)
        262                     if '%Z' in format or '%z' in format:
        263                         return _return_parsed_timezone_results(

     pandas/_libs/tslibs/strptime.pyx in 
     pandas._libs.tslibs.strptime.array_strptime()

     ValueError: unconverted data remains: 0
```

Help me convert those float numbers to time.

I cannot convert the integer directly as the datetime needs a proper format, that is including the zeroes.

The expected version of DEPARTURE_TIME looks like this:

`0    08:00:00
1    08:30:00
2    19:10:00
3    15:15:00
4    14:27:00
Name: SCHEDULED_DEPARTURE, dtype: object`

Comment: could you show the `SCHEDULED_DEPARTURE` rows example before conversion to time?

Comment: @ALFAFA `SCHEDULED_DEPARTURE`  row is in int64 dtype, so that means 8:00 will be 0800, 19:10 will be 1910 instead of 1910.0 like other float value rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of a "true" input file, I used the following string:

```
data="""xx,DEPARTURE_TIME
f1,0800.0
f2,0830.0
f3,1910.0
f4,1515.0
f5,1427.0"""
```

so the input is limited to *DEPARTURE_TIME* and *xx* representing other columns.

As the conversion function I defined:

```
def cnv(src):
    return f'{src[0:2]}:{src[2:4]}:00'
```

It will be used to convert *DEPARTURE_TIME* column.

The *src* parameter is a *string* - a part of input row concerning the
respective column. The returned value is: first 2 chars, next 2 chars
and *00*, with *:* between them.

And to read the source CSV I used:

```
df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(data),\
    converters={'DEPARTURE_TIME': cnv})
```

In your program, read from your input file (instead of *StringIO*).

For now *DEPARTURE_TIME* column is of *string* type.

But if for any reason you want to have this column as *time*,
you can do another conversion:

```
df.DEPARTURE_TIME = pd.to_datetime(
    df.DEPARTURE_TIME, format= '%H:%M:%S' ).dt.time
```

When you *print(df)*, both before and after the above instruction
you will get just the same output:

```
   xx DEPARTURE_TIME
0  f1       08:00:00
1  f2       08:30:00
2  f3       19:10:00
3  f4       15:15:00
4  f5       14:27:00
```

But if you run `type(df.iloc[0,1])`, you will see that after conversion the type
is *datetime.time* (before it was *str*).

On the other hand, if you run `df.info()` you will see that both before and after
the last conversion the type of *DEPARTURE_TIME* column is **object**.

The same approach you can use to other input columns formatted as *float*s.

Comment: Holy crap, you just single-handedly saved my internship project, thank you so much